# Ico Sphere Subdivisions Missing

Tags: blender

I am using Blender to create some Ico Spheres for a project. The videos on Youtube show how to perform this quickly and increase the number of subdivisions. With the new blender though I cannot locate the tab that allows you to change the subdivisions.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

When you add new Ico Sphere operator is located at bottom left corner. Click little arrow to expand operator and adjust parameters if you need to.

[Ico sphere operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpWqJ.png)